# Push / Pull cash from one account into other accounts and keep track of balances by account

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to push/pull cash from one account into other accounts and keep track of balances by account.  The best model I can think of to explain this is "petty cash".  There is a primary "petty cash" account that has cash in it and then other accounts pull cash out and put cash back in (in a FIFO manner).  Once all transactions are processed, I want to know how much petty cash has been moved to each of the other accounts.

**Specs**

1. Account balances should never go negative; once petty cash is depleted, no more can be pulled to an account
2. Transactions are to be processed in a FIFO fashion
3. Negative account transactions pull money out of petty cash account and positive account transaction amounts put money back

**Example data setup**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY, account_id int, date DATE, amount int);

INSERT INTO transactions (account_id, date, amount) VALUES
 /* Petty cash account transaction; 
    all other accounts will pull from this cash */
 (1, '2017-01-01', 5),

 /* Other account transactions that will
    pull from petty cash */
 (2, '2017-01-02', -2),
 (3, '2017-01-03', -8),
 (4, '2017-01-04', -6),
 (3, '2017-01-05', 10),
 (2, '2017-01-06', 1);
```

**Expected output**

```
| account_id | cash_balance | notes                                              | 
|------------|--------------|----------------------------------------------------| 
| 1          | 0            | Petty cash account depleted                        | 
| 2          | 1            | Total spending was -1                              | 
| 3          | 0            | Total spending was +2, we gave all petty cash back | 
| 4          | 4            | Total spending was -6, we had 4 left to pull       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this.  Using a 2 step process, I first calculate an "adjusted amount" for each account transaction which reduces the spending by any available refunds on the same account, FIFO.  Then, in step 2, I "pull" from petty cash using these adjusted amounts, FIFO.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY, account_id int, date DATE, amount int);

INSERT INTO transactions (account_id, date, amount) VALUES
 /* Petty cash account transaction; 
    all other accounts will pull from this cash */
 (1, '2017-01-01', 5),

 /* Other account transactions that will
    pull from petty cash */
 (2, '2017-01-02', -2),
 (3, '2017-01-03', -8),
 (4, '2017-01-04', -6),
 (3, '2017-01-05', 10),
 (2, '2017-01-06', 1);


WITH e_adjusted_amounts AS (
    SELECT id, account_id, amount,
        /* adjusted_amount: the amount adjusted for returns, FIFO.
       This gives us a logical amount for outflows, adjusted for corresponding inflows
       that can be used later when we start pulling from petty cash. */
        amount - LEAST(0, GREATEST(amount,
            -(  -- total of all preceeding outflows
                COALESCE((SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE amount < 0) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY id)) - amount,0)
                -- total of all inflows
              + COALESCE(SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE amount > 0) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id),0)

             )
            )
        ) as adjusted_amount
    FROM transactions
),
e_pull_amounts AS (
    SELECT a.id, a.account_id, a.amount, a.adjusted_amount, LEAST(0, GREATEST(a.adjusted_amount,
             -(  petty_cash.amount
                 -- total of all preceeding outflows
               + COALESCE((SUM(a.adjusted_amount) OVER (ORDER BY id)) - a.adjusted_amount,0)
             )
            )
        ) as pull_amount
    FROM e_adjusted_amounts a,
        (SELECT amount FROM transactions WHERE account_id = 1) petty_cash
    -- Outflows only
    WHERE adjusted_amount < 0
    AND account_id != 1
)
SELECT account_id, SUM(pull_amount) as cash_balance
FROM e_pull_amounts
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY account_id;
```